# ASP.NET Core app publish : web.config incorrectly generated for framework-dependant deployment

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, .net-core, iis, asp.net-core-6.0

I'm trying to publish a .NET Core 6.0 web app and host it using IIS on a Windows server.

My publication settings are as follows :

```xml
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <DeleteExistingFiles>true</DeleteExistingFiles>
    <ExcludeApp_Data>false</ExcludeApp_Data>
    <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>true</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Release</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <PublishProvider>FileSystem</PublishProvider>
    <PublishUrl>bin\Release\net6.0\publish\</PublishUrl>
    <WebPublishMethod>FileSystem</WebPublishMethod>
    <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish />
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ProjectGuid>25e664a3-e6f3-40b0-9e3d-02f03e3df3f7</ProjectGuid>
    <SelfContained>false</SelfContained>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
    <PublishSingleFile>false</PublishSingleFile>
    <PublishReadyToRun>false</PublishReadyToRun>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

I'm having an issue with the auto-generated web.config file.
The aspNetCore section seems to be generated for a self-contained deployment :

```xml
<aspNetCore processPath=".\myApp.exe" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
```

According to [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/web-config?view=aspnetcore-7.0#configuration-of-aspnet-core-module-with-webconfig), here is what it should look like instead :

```xml
<aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\myApp.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
```

I'm using the latest VS2022 version and .NET Core 6 SDK.

I tried adding

```xml
<RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
```

To the .csproj file (I had no runtime specified before) but that made no difference.

What could explain this behavior ? Any ideas as to how to solve the problem ?

I know I can write my own web.config file but I would like to avoid that if possible.

Thank you

EDIT :
So, after some more digging, I tried to run the app executable directly and got this error :

```
Could not resolve CoreCLR path.
```

Then after reading this issue https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/10051 I tried to remove the `hostfxr.dll` file from the generated files, and then the exe ran fine !

The hosting bundle is correctly installed on the server... now I'm even more confused.

Answer (score 1):

This is correct, you don't need to modify it.

Publishing an app as framework-dependent produces a cross-platform binary as a dll file, and a platform-specific executable that targets your current platform. The dll is cross-platform while the executable isn't.

For example:

Framework-dependent deployment produces a cross-platform .dll file that uses the locally installed .NET runtime.

```
dotnet publish HelloWorld -c Release
```

Framework-dependent executable produces a platform-specific executable that uses the locally installed .NET runtime.

```
dotnet publish HelloWorld -c Release -r win-x64 --self-contained false
```

Note that in both framework-dependent scenarios, HelloWorld.dll is a regular .NET assembly. HelloWorld.exe is here to locate the corresponding .NET install on the machine and bootstrap the .NET runtime. Then the .NET runtime loads and runs HelloWorld.dll. Obviously HelloWorld.exe is not a .NET assembly.

In addition, in your publication settings, you can clearly see that `SelfContained` is `false`.

Helpful link: [Deployment models](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/#publish-framework-dependent).

Comment: If I try to run the generated exe, I get the following error : "Could not resolve CoreCLR path". Here is the dotnet --info output :
`Host:
  Version:      6.0.12
  Architecture: x64
  Commit:       02e45a41b7

.NET SDKs installed:
  No SDKs were found.

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.12 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.12 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]`

Comment: Also, it seems to me that your explanation contradicts the docs I linked, are the docs wrong ? thanks

Comment: Do you get this error when you run the exe file directly? Did you [restart IIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/hosting-bundle?view=aspnetcore-7.0#restart-iis) after installing the hosting bundle? @Marc F

Comment: Yes, I get the error when I try to run the exe directly from command line. I did restart IIS. I edited my initial question with more information. The exe runs fine ONLY IF I delete `hostfxr.dll` from the files. I haven't found much info about this file and what it's supposed to do though...

Answer (score 0):

I tried a default MVC application without any changes. The publication settings is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=208121.
-->
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <DeleteExistingFiles>false</DeleteExistingFiles>
    <ExcludeApp_Data>false</ExcludeApp_Data>
    <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>true</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Release</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <PublishProvider>FileSystem</PublishProvider>
    <PublishUrl>E:\Publish\testmvc</PublishUrl>
    <WebPublishMethod>FileSystem</WebPublishMethod>
    <_TargetId>Folder</_TargetId>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

It published as a framework-dependent one.

```
<aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\tesmvc.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
```

If I add

```
<RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
```

It will publish as a self-contained format:

```
<aspNetCore processPath=".\tesmvc.exe" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
```

So I think just leave the "TargetRuntme" as portable maybe a good idea.
[image]

Comment: From my understanding, `RuntimeIdentifier` will generate an exe that looks for the specified runtime and throws an error if it isn't installed. So, confusing documentation aside, it should still work as long as the runtime is installed. On my server, I get an error though (see my edited question). The error goes away if I delete `hostfxr.dll`, but I have no idea why..

Comment: Also, `portable` should work, I was in fact already using it as a workaround before, but at this point it's more about understanding the issue than having something that works !

Comment: Actually,  add <RuntimeIdentifier> worked as normal on my machine. How about reinstall your sdk and runtimes?